# 'NoneType' object is not callable. why? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I'd like to print out some with the help of the decorator, but  get a nonetype error**

```
def deco(func):
    def wrapper():
        return "<it>{}</it>".format(func)

@deco
def funct():
    return 'some'

funct()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: show the traceback

Comment: `deco` doesn't return anything. Nothing inside `deco` calls `wrapper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
def deco(func):
    def wrapper():
        return "<it>{}</it>".format(func())
    return wrapper

@deco
def funct():
    return 'some'

print(funct())
```

output

```
<it>some</it>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `wrapper()` is never called, `deco` returns `None`. You then attempt to call this return value, which causes the error.

To fix it, just return the wrapper in your decorator:

```
return wrapper
```